# Multiple colors in Toolbar title?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-toolbar, android-styles

I want to set my Toolbar title to "Videos (4)" where the "Videos" part is one color, and the "(4)" part is another color. I want to use colors from my `colors.xml` resource file.

How can I do this?

Here is how I'm setting the Toolbar title:

```
getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Videos (" + numVideos + ")");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set custom font and colors with spannable.

Try this:

```
protected void setActionBarTitle(String title) {
    //if API level below 18, there is a bug at Samsung and LG devices
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2) {
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);
    } else {
        SpannableString s = new SpannableString(title);
        s.setSpan(new TypefaceSpan(this, "Your-Font.ttf"), 0, s.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        s.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(), R.color.colorAccent)), 0, s.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(s);
    }


}
```

In your case, this should work:

```
SpannableString firstPart = new SpannableString("Videos ");
SpannableString lastPart = new SpannableString(" (4)");

firstPart.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(), R.color.white)), 0, firstPart.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

lastPart.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(), R.color.black)), 0, lastPart.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```

then set your title thike this:

```
getSupportActionBar().setTitle(firstPart + lastPart);
```

or like this:

```
getSupportActionBar().setTitle(TextUtils.concat(firstPart, lastPart));
```

Comment: This doesn't explain how to use multiple colors in a single Toolbar title. Nor do I want to change the font.

Comment: @user486123 At first, I told you the logic behind this. Just updated my answer/

Comment: Had to use `TextUtils.concat(firstPart, lastPart)` instead of `firstPart + lastPart`, but thanks!

Comment: @user486123 updated my answer according to your feedback

Answer (score 0):

```
String text = "<font color=#cc0029>Videos</font> <font color=#ffcc00>(" + numVideos + ")</font>"; 

getSupportActionBar().setTitle(Html.fromHtml(text));
```

Comment: "I want to use colors from my `colors.xml` resource file."

Comment: these case you directly mention color inside font tag